# Запятые в примерах с (дее)причастными оборотами

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, синтаксис

Как расставить запятые?

1. Да ты сам, ничего не замечая, ходишь по дому как слепой! (правильно ?)
2. Объявление в автобусе (дословно, с сохранением пунктуации):

   О фактах совершения карманных краж и обнаружении лиц, их совершивших постарайтесь как можно скорее сообщить об этом водителю, кондуктору или в полицию

По-моему, нужна  запятая после "совершивших," или нет?

Answer (score 2):

***Да ты сам, ничего не замечая, ходишь по дому как слепой!***(= ходишь слепым) Запятую не ставим.

Объявление в автобусе нужно править, так как оно составлено с грамматическими и речевыми ошибками. ОБ ЭТОМ - убираем, так как уже есть О ФАКТАХ. СООБЩИТЬ (о чём?)о фактах... и (о чём? о ком?) о лицах.... :

***О фактах карманных краж и о лицах, их совершивших, просим немедленно сообщать водителю, кондуктору или полицейским.*** Запятая нужна, причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова.

Answer (score 1):

Да ты сам, ничего не замечая, ходишь по дому, как слепой!- Сравнительный оборот нужно отделить запятой.

О фактах совершения карманных краж и обнаружении лиц, их совершивших, постарайтесь как можно скорее сообщить об этом водителю, кондуктору или в полицию.- Да, запятая нужна, она закрывает причастный оборот.

Answer (score 0):

А. Да ты сам, ничего не замечая, ходишь по дому, как слепой!

В принципе оборот нужно обособить, так как признак назван два раза: ходишь (1) ничего не замечая, ходишь (2) как слепой.

Б. Но позиция оборота (в конце предложения) неудобна для обособления, интонация неестественная, поэтому желательно предложение переделать, и  тогда обособление не требуется (обстоятельства можно представить в виде однородного ряда):

Да ты сам ходишь по дому  как слепой, ничего не замечая.